# Unity - Window size depending on Screen size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like my game to have a 1:1 aspect ratio, but scaled up to a certain amount. Meaning that the width and height must be identical, but never larger than the actual screen size. Ontop of that, to ensure consistent pixel sizes the width and height values must be power of 2 value.

I didn't have any problems figuring out the needed value.

```
int value = 2;
int limit = Screen.currentResolution.height;
while (value * 2 < limit) value *= 2;
Debug.Log(value);
```

I much rather have no idea how to set the window size BEFORE the splash image is even shown. Is there any way how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is, but that means that you'll need to get rid of the launch window.

The reason is that, if you enable the launch window (from which you can select resolutions, quality, windowed or fullscreen mode etc.), Unity will show **only** the video card available resolutions - and this means no 1:1 aspect ratio resolutions available.

So, in order to do this, you need to setup the Player Settings as follows:

[image]

The important part is to disable the `Display Resolution Dialog`.
Then you set the `Default Screen Width` and `Height` by disabling the `Default Is Native Resolution`.

Notice that the standalone will be forced to this, and only this, resolution at start - after the splash screen you can set whatever resolution you want by calling the `Screen.SetResolution` method from any script in the first scene loaded.
Of course you can make the standalone start in windowed or fullscreen mode, by unticking/ticking the `Default Is Full Screen` option.

That's pretty much it, if you wanted to give the user the option to choose from a list of 1:1 AR resolutions, you simply just can't at the moment afaik.

**Edit**: The resolution info of the Player Settings are stored in the registry inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\[YourCompanyName]\[YourGameName]`.
The 3 keys are these:

```
Screenmanager Is Fullscreen mode
Screenmanager Resolution Height
Screenmanager Resolution Width
```

To change those from inside the game at runtime, you need to use:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Screenmanager Is Fullscreen mode", [0/1]);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Screenmanager Resolution Height", [HeighthRes]);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Screenmanager Resolution Width", [WidthRes]);
```

These will be read the next time the game is launched, setting the starting resolution before the splash screen.

Comment: It is a pretty good solution, I already had most parts of this, but thank you anyway :) It doesn't answer my main question though, which was how to set the size before the splash screen.

Comment: @IanH. I thought you knew where Unity stores that resolution information, I'll edit my answer to amend that.